# Running wordpress on localhost

Tags: localhost

I have installed a copy of my live site onto localhost, and site itself runs fine. However if I try to sign in to back in, my credentials are accepted, but relocated to localhost/dashboard. I have checked homepage and site URL are correct in Database. If have also deleted htaccess. What else can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by: my credentials are accepted, but relocated to localhost/dashboard? Are you getting redirected after a successful login?

Comment: there is no popup to state that either username or password are incorrect